# Can't stop iOS scheduleLocalNotification

Tags: swift, ios9, uilocalnotification

I'm not sure if it is technical issues. I tried to implement a scheduled local notification by calling this:

```
// Schedule the notification ********************************************
    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications.count == 0 {

        let notification = UILocalNotification()
        notification.alertBody = "This is local push notification"
        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
        notification.fireDate = NSDate()
        notification.category = categoryID
        notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Minute

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
    }
```

from

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {
}
```

It works fine. However, when I revert the code to the origin version without any line of codes related to the **scheduleLocalNotification()** the local notification still running.
I can't stop it even I clean the project/remove the application from devices before a rebuild.

Please help if possible, thank you!

Comment: There is no such thing as a "local push" notification. Either it's a push notification or it's a local notification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have created a repeating local notification and handed it to the system. At that point it is *out of your hands*. You have told the system to repeat this notification, and it will do so, *forever*.

Your only choice at this point is to delete your app.

What you have done is a classic mistake — one, unfortunately, that many apps do in fact make. And I have had to delete *those* apps from *my* device as well, as there is no other way to stop the repeating notification.

The *right* thing to do would have been to build into your app a cancelation of that local notification, i.e. you stop the notification *in code*. For example, you tell the UIApplication shared instance to [`cancelAllLocalNotifications`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1622990-cancelalllocalnotifications). But you failed to do that.

Comment: Thank you. I called this before cancelAllLocalNotifications() but it still not works.

Comment: Perhaps you changed your bundle id? In that case you are no longer the same app.

Comment: Anyhow I would try force-rebooting the device.

Comment: No, the bundle id still the same, I also tried to force-rebooting but still not works. Anyway, thank you for the answer, I know the reason from that.

Comment: Also notification delivery is up to your Settings so you can always just turn them off entirely! :)

Comment: I can do it but the app required push notification for some functions. :))

Comment: Updated: I call cancelAllLocalNotifications() again after one day and some reboot times and it fixed. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad you didn't have to smash the device with a hammer. That was going to be my next suggestion!